# load 32 bit immediate value in RISCV memory

Tags: assembly, memory, 32-bit, riscv, instructions

I am trying to store a 32 bit immediate value in a riscv memory location.The corresponding code is

```
lui x13,0x12345
addi x13,x13,0x678   // 32 bit value- 12345678
lui x11, 0x1c010     // address location 1c01000
sw x13,x11
```

The problem I am facing is during simulation  32 bit value is not found in the address location(1c01000). Address location shows only 1 byte of the given data(78)

Comment: The value shown in 1c01000 location is 78787878

Comment: Are you sure there is (simulated) memory at that address?  Try it at a more "usual" address, e.g. 0x10000000 or 0x10010000, to see if that works as expected.  Otherwise, declare the data: `.data ... label: .word 0 ... .text ... la x11, label; sw x13,(x11)`.  This way the data should get a valid memory address.

Comment: Also, there is a typo in your example, should read `sw x13,(x11)` -or- `sw x13,0(x11)`.  What assembler & simulator are you using?

Comment: sw x13,(x11) simulator using is Gtkwave

Comment: I checked the memory banks separately 78 is copied in all the four banks, memory write is not done at that time.

Answer (score 1):

RISC-V is byte-addressable.  If you only checked the one byte at that address, obviously it will contain only 1 byte of the 4-byte value.

You need to check the whole 32-bit word at that address, or the 4 bytes 1c01000 .. 1c01003 separately.

Comment: I checked the memory banks separately 78 is copied in all the four banks, memory write is not done at that time..Is there any error with my program?